# Delete command not working in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Im using below shell script and DELETE functionality not working. I do not have any idea where is the issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi1"
find /home/tmp/Deltest -name "*.*" -type f -mtime +5 -delete
echo "$?"
```

Files modified date is below on folder(/home/tmp/Deltest)

```
-rw-r-----. 1 abc-user abc-user 3 Sep 16 12:43 abc.txt
-rw-r-----. 1 abc-user abc-user 4 Sep 16 12:44 abc1.txt
-rw-r-----. 1 abc-user abc-user 3 Sep 16 12:44 def.txt
```

I want to delete all files which is more than 5 days.

Comment: I tried your script and it works as expected. Are you getting any kind of error messages?

Comment: No error. $? also printing 0 only.

Comment: if you remove `-delete`, does it list your files?

Comment: yes. if I remove "-delete" option, it is listing all eligible files(older than 5 days). Output:      hi1
/home/tmp/Deltest/def.txt
/home/tmp/Deltest/abc1.txt
/home/tmp/Deltest/abc.txt
0

Comment: @Srinivasan,Maybe there are some permissions issue (SElinux enabled, or directory permission doesn't allow to delete file (file permissions are related only for write/read and directory permissions are about creating/deleting files)
Can you try to remove one of these files manually from the same user using "rm <file>" command?

Comment: yes. I can remove files by using "rm" command.

Comment: @srinivasan, along the same lines as saboteur's comment, how are you running this script? It may be a permissions issue although maybe you could try a different syntax? I.e., `find /home/tmp/Deltest -name "*.*" -type f -mtime +5 | xargs rm -rf`

Comment: if i use "| xargs rm -rf" command, it is deleting all files. however it is deleting files in sub folder also. And moreover why "-delete" option not deleting files.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question about why "find" does not seem to accept the "-delete" parameter https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/finds-exec-rm-vs-delete

Answer (score 1):

After removing "#!/bin/bash", it is working. But do not know what is the reason for it.

Comment: Some versions of find don't have the option for a `-delete` flag. The one in /bin/bash probably doesn't have it but maybe your own account is running a different shell. If you want to know the answer to your question it is very specific to your system and configuration. You could try to find out which shell you're using by typing `echo "$SHELL"` or discover where the find executable is located by typing `which find` in the shell.